# ms access unwanted "Enter Parameter Value" when using combobox in a form

Tags: ms-access

I have form which contains a few combo boxes and some text boxes. There is another combo box (the row source is from another table) which needs to be filtered by the values the user entered in the previous combo boxes and text boxes but even if you entered the values you get the "Enter Parameter Value" message for each one. I used the expression builder for every criterion so its unlikely that there are any typos. What can cause this message to appear?

Code for the combo box's row source:

```
SELECT      Profiles.profile 
FROM        Profiles 
WHERE       (((Profiles.Type)=[Forms]![AddItem]![typeComboBox]) AND 
            ((Profiles.WindowOrDoor)=[Forms]![AddItem]![windowDoorComboBox]) AND 
            ((Profiles.MaximumWidthPerWing)>[Forms]![AddItem]![widthUserInput]) AND 
            ((Profiles.MaximumHeightPerWing)>[Forms]![AddItem]![heightUserInput]))
```

Comment: Welcome to the board.  It's hard to understand what problem you're getting at without some examples and looking at the code you've already written.  Could you add some screenshots and the SQL you're using in the combo-boxes.  You'll more than likely find the SQL in the `Row Source` (_Data_ tab on the _Property Sheet_ for the control) - will start something like _SELECT ..... FROM...._.  If you're using a named query - open it in design view, click the arrow next to _View_ and select _SQL View_.

Comment: Would also be worth while reading [tour], [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: This is called cascading/dependent combo or list box. Very common topic. Edit question to show combobox RowSource SQL. I never use expression builder.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook Added.

Comment: @June7 Added row source

Answer (score 0):

The SQL statement is in the RowSource, not a query object? If the controls are all on the same form, no need for the full form path reference. Works for me. Try:

```
SELECT      profile 
FROM        Profiles 
WHERE       [Type] = [typeComboBox] AND 
            WindowOrDoor = [windowDoorComboBox] AND 
            MaximumWidthPerWing > [widthUserInput] AND 
            MaximumHeightPerWing > [heightUserInput]
```

I think Type is a reserved word, hence the [ ].

If it still prompts for input then Access can't find those names.

You also need code to requery the combobox. Put it in the form Current event as well as the combobox GotFocus event.

Be aware, cascading combobox doesn't play nice with continuous or datasheet form.